# Comparison of stochastic integrals

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Suppose that $T>0$, $(\alpha_t)_{0 \leq t \leq T}$ is a stochastic process such that there exists a constant $a>0$ so that for all $t\in[0, T], \alpha_t \geq a$. Let $(W_t)_t$ a Brownian motion. Is it true that
$$\sup_{0\leq t \leq T}\int_0^t a dW_s \leq \sup_{0\leq t\leq T}\int_0^t \alpha_s dW_s \quad a.s. \quad?$$

Comment: No. For example, take $\alpha_t =1$ for all $t$ and $a=0$. Then $\int_0^t a\,dW_s=0$ and $\int_0^t \alpha_s\,dW_s=W_t$. Clearly it is not the case that $W_t\ge 0$ a.s.

Comment: But we have that $\sup_{t} W_t\geq W_0 =0$ a.s.